# LINQ to Entities not supported

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

In Asp.net Web API I'm having the following model.

```
public class User
    {
        [Required, Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Company Employer { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is an extract from one of the controllers.

```
// GET api/Company/5
    public Object GetCompany(int id)
    {
        var query = from user in db.Users
                    join company in db.Companies on user.Employer.Id equals company.Id
                    where company.Id == id
                    orderby user.Name
                    select new { Id = user.Id, Name = user.Name, EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress, Version = user.DateAdded.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), Employer = company.Name };
        return query.AsEnumerable<Object>();
    }
```

What I want is to format the DateAdded property. However, EF throws a NotSupportedException when I try to invoke a method on one of the user's properties or invoke a method of the user. How can I still format the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF cannot translate `user.DateAdded.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")` method into SQL code. You should either move date formatting to client side (with `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` call) or use [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build date string on server side:

```
Version = 
   SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", user.DateAdded) + "." +
   SqlFunctions.StringConvert(
       (decimal?)SqlFunctions.DatePart("MM", user.DateAdded)).Trim() + "." +
   SqlFunctions.DateName("yyyy", user.DateAdded)
```

Comment: Great, thank you! How to get the different date parts is descriped here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174395.aspx . Is there still a way of getting the month as a number?

Comment: @user2558051 sorry, forgot about month. Updated sample with getting it as number (you will need to use `StringConvert` and `DatePart` for that)